# MongoDB - calculated condition on delete

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Example collection with documents:

```
{ _id: ObjectId(...), value: 19293 },
{ _id: ObjectId(...), value: 32123 }
```

I want to delete all documents, where `value % 1000 == 123`, to leave in collection only:

```
{ _id: ObjectId(...), value: 19293 }
```

I know how to find required documents with `aggregate` -

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { filterValue: { $mod: ["$value", 1000] } } },
    { $match: { filterValue: 123 } }
])
```

After which I can delete everything I found. But I am interesting in how to delete all documents immediately in `db.test.deleteMany({ ??? }), without searching before. I cannot do:

```
db.test.deleteMany({
    { $mod: ["$value", 1000] }: 123
})
```

How can I do what am I trying to?

Comment: Can you try `db.collection.delete({
        $expr: { $eq: [ { $mod: ["$value", 1000] }, 123 ]  }
    })` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) expression with `$eq` condition,

```
db.test.deleteMany({
    $expr: {
        $eq: [
            { $mod: ["$value", 1000] },
            123
        ]
    }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AjNGan-Ai0h)